# Way to copy the values from column1(containing numbers) declared as varchar to another column2 declared as number in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am using a table say employee, which has two columns-mobileno and landlineno (both declared as varchar) contains the contact number of that employee.
So now we are moving a step ahead by adding two additional columnms mn and fn both declared as bigint.
So I wrote an  update query which updated the values.
Since the table has grown large, so it contains many junk values like 052-12525, which was inserted from from frontend, the value copied in mn is 052 ignoring the digits after "-".
And 1 more instance is the mobileno is 5.836 which was incorrectly entered from front end was copied as 6.
So please suggest me if there is  a way in which the characters can be ignored and only the digits should be copied to the new column

Comment: What about phone numbers like `+442071231234`?  If you store that as a BigInt, then convert it back to text, you get `0442071231234`, which is wrong...  I think you're better off checking the strings that are entered and enforcing constraints on them (on the user) before they reach the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) and [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
SELECT REPLACE('052-12525', '-', ''), FORMAT(12332.1,0)
```

will return 05212525 and 12332